# How does a function with a void array pointer argument know the size of array elements?

Tags: c, pointers, void

Page 121 of K&R lists the following function for swapping two array elements:

```
void swap(void *v[], int i, int j)
{
    void *temp;

    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;
}
```

I don't understand how indexing into the array can work when the array does not have a type.

As far as I am aware, types do not exist at runtime and there is no guarantee that this function would be compiled along with the code that uses it.

How then is it possible for this function to correctly perform array indexing when an array containing values of any size could be passed to it?

In other words, if I passed a `long` array to this function, how would it know that `v[i]` would be located at `v + sizeof(long) * i` when it does not know the type of the array?

Comment: it is the same as `void swap(long x[], int i, int j)` except with `void*` instead of `long`.  You cannot pass a `long` array to the function in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array *does* have a type.  It is an array of `void *`, and a `void *` is a fully defined type, unlike `void`.

So what this function is doing is swapping a pair of `void *` in the array.

If `v` was defined as `void *` instead of `void *[]`, then you would have a problem.

Comment: Ah, I see. `void *v[]` is an array of void pointers, not a pointer to an array of voids.